# Si tiene importancia ... querría verlo

Tags: gramática

Quisiera confirmar si de verdad "[No sé si tiene importancia, pero pensé que quizá querría verlo](https://www.espanolavanzado.com/gramatica-avanzada/398-quiza-subjuntivo)" es una construcción condicional. Es que en mi opinión si es una construcción condicional, entonces debería hacer "si tuviera importancia" en vez de "si tiene importancia", ¿no es así? ¡Muchas gracias de antemano!

Answer (score 1):

La oración:

- No sé si tiene importancia, pero pensé que quizá querría verlo

NO es una oración condicional.

Lo que la página mencionada dice es que el modo indicativo puede usarse con el tiempo condicional o potencial.

En efecto, a diferencia de la oración:

- Si tuviera el dinero, quizá me compraría una furgoneta nueva

que es en efecto una oración condicional con pretérito imperfecto del subjuntivo en la condición y condicional simple en el resultado, en la oración:

- No sé si tiene importancia, pero pensé que quizá querría verlo

lo que observamos es dos proposiciones coordinadas por la conjunción "pero".

La primera proposición contiene una cláusula nominal "si tiene importancia", donde "si" no es condicional (es el "whether" del inglés, que también puede reemplazarse por el "if" que introduce "content clauses"), mientas que la segunda proposición contiene un condicional que expresa FUTURO DESDE UNA PERSPECTIVA PASADA:

Mi pensamiento en ese momento: "Pienso que querrá verlo."

En pasado: "Pensé que querría verlo."

La oración sería condicional y combinaría indicativo con potencial si fuera:

- Si tiene importancia, querría verlo.

donde "querría" expresa un deseo en forma más tentativa que el menos usual:

- Si tiene importancia, quiero verlo.

El uso del condicional "querría" tiene que ver con la naturaleza del verbo "querer", que expresa un deseo. Con otros verbos, la combinación de tiempos verbales sería probablemente diferente:

- Si tiene importante, lo veré.
- Si tuviera importancia, lo vería.